Ninguna sobrecarga coincide con esta llamada. ts(2769)
soy nuevo con React Native y SQLite, estoy intentando desarrollar un CRUD, primero cree la base de datos, luego intente hacer un select como viene en documentación y foros, pero no consigo que me los muestre en pantalla, como digo soy nuevo en esto y estoy intentando aprender lo básico.
Al tratar de hacer la consulta para que me traiga algunos datos de la bd me aparece error.
Adjunto mi código:


import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";

export default function ListProducts(props: any) {
    const [names, setNames] = useState<string[]>([]); // Asegúrate de especificar el tipo correcto para names

    useEffect(() => {
        const initializeDatabase = async () => {
            try {
                const db = await SQLite.openDatabase({
                    name: "mydata.db",
                    createFromLocation: 'default'
                });

                db.transaction(tx => {
                    // Crear la tabla si no existe
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)');

                    // Consulta SELECT para obtener los nombres de los productos
                    tx.executeSql(
                        "SELECT * FROM products",
                        [],
                        (_, result) => {
                            // Obtener los nombres y actualizar el estado
                            const productNames = Array.from(result.rows).map(row => row.name);
                            setNames(productNames);
                        },
                        (_, error) => {
                            console.error("Error al consultar productos:", error);
                        }
                    );
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error al abrir la base de datos:", error);
            }
        };

        initializeDatabase();
    }, []);

    return (
        // Renderiza tu componente aquí
        <View>
            {names.map((name, index) => (
                <Text key={index}>{name}</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}



Aquí muestro imagen del error:

